# Guess the number

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$.

I choose a number, and feed you subsets of $S$ one at a time, each one containing my number. In this case the set magnitude is $4$.

What is the least number of sets I can feed you so that I have told you my number? And the most before I reveal my number?

Comment: "set magnitude is 4" meaning that you'll only give us subsets of size $4$ containing your number?

Comment: yes, also note the ordering of the subsets is irrelevant; @pjs36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the subsets you feed are all different, the minimum necessary number of them is $2$ (though this will change if we'll deal with subsets of 6 or more elements), and the maximum without revealing the answer is the number of subsets which all share the same **two** elements (so that we wouldn't know the right one), which in your case is $C_{4-2}^{10-2}=C_2^8={8\cdot7\over2}=28$.

Comment: nice - i had it as $4$. what if magnitude is $6$?

Comment: With 6, you would need a minimum of 3 subsets, and in general case, $\left\lceil{N-1\over N-n}\right\rceil$, where $N$ is your 10, $n$ is your 4 or 6, and $\lceil\dots\rceil$ is rounding up.